# Need a field that will count the number of days between date1 and today but stop counting once date 2 is filled in

Tags: formula-field

I'm working on building out an SLA tracker that will look at a date in the case (date1 in my example) and subtract the days between date1 and today. However, I also need it to stop counting once another field in the case (date2) is filled in. Is this possible? I know how I can get the count working but not how to have it reference another field to stop the count.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomend a new formula field.

Go to Object -> Fields & Relationships -> New -> Formula -> number

Set the number of decimals to show.
give it a name

If you are working with dates something like this will work:

```
if( 
    isblank(date2), 
    today()- date1 , 
    date2 - date1
)
```

If you are working with date times you will need to wrap their field names with the dateValue() function like this:

```
if( 
    isblank(dateTime2), 
    today()- dateValue(dateTime1) , 
    dateValue(dateTime2)-dateValue(dateTime1)
)
```